# Is editing questions which contains full site name is allowed?

Tags: discussion

I saw some of questions with includes full site name : http://sitename.com

can we edit this as [link](http://sitename.com) because if we write full site name, than google will nicely crawl the link and if some customer search for the site in google, instead of showing site url in search results page, it will show
magento stack exchange link & if client search for site, its going to be very bad.
so can we edit these kind of questions or keep it as it is ?

Comment: here also downvotes , thanks man :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For examples one should use the example domains defined in [RFC-2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606)

- *.example
- *.example.com
- *.example.net
- *.example.org

I have edited some questions that accidently disclosed a real site domain or used actually existing domains like "domain.com" or "test.com" as example to replace those with example domains as above and would encourage anybody else to do the same.

**Linking** to a site should almost never be necessary. To show how something looks, upload a screenshots instead.

Comment: Fantastic, you are absolutely right. I have the same opinion.